# Best practices for dealing with nested dicts?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, data-structures, hash

I am loading data from a CSV to a db Model. I use an intermediate layer for data validation. Here's a basic example:

```
{'Team': 
  {'Account': 
    {'InvoiceID' : invID,
     'Amount': aLotOfMoney}
}}

for team in teams.:
     for account in teams[team]:
         for invoice in teams[team][account]:
             acc = Account(ID = teams[team][account][invoiceID],
                           amount=teams[team][account][amount])
             acc.save()
```

This works fine and all but it's far from elegant and seems rather inefficient. Is there a way to return the nested `Dict` instead of the `key`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to flatten the dictionary? I.e. you would get one dictionary, and each key would be a combination of its keys in each dictionary.

You could use a premade function like [flatten-dict](https://pypi.org/project/flatten-dict/), or you could write something yourself.

This sample nested dict:

```
{'ints': {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3}, 'letters': {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}}
```

would be flattened into:

```
{'ints.1': 1, 'ints.2': 2, 'ints.3': 3, 'letters.a': 'A', 'letters.b': 'B'}
```

Homemade:

```
def flatten_dict(data, keystring=''):
    if type(data) is dict:
        keystring = keystring + '.' if keystring else keystring
        for k in data:
            yield from flatten_dict(data[k], keystring + k)
    else:
        yield keystring, data
```

Comment: The exact opposite. I want the inner nested Dicts with the links preserved instead of just the key. In your solution, I would then have to split the key to get the last part. I need the 3 dict levels for meta data in the business logic and would like to preserve their hierarchy.